# Android Studio Project for JNI library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am writing a JNI library for Android, to be distributed and shared across several projects.

I found tutorials on creating an Android application that includes native code. I found tutorials on adding JNI libraries to an existing application.

However I did not find how to create a standalone JNI library on Android Studio. When creating a new project it automatically assumed I want to create an application, there is no option for creating a library.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#CreateLibrary

Comment: "To create a new library module in your project..." - it assumed an already existing project.

Comment: And it also seems to be only valid for android/java libraries. Not JNI.

Comment: create a new project that supports C/C++ and add `Library Module` to that project

Comment: The problem is the "create a new project" step, it asks me to choose activity etc... It creates an application.

Comment: and you dont have `Add No Activity`?

Comment: I do, but it still creates an application, with manifest, java files etc. Same for adding a library module, it's all Java etc. I'm trying to create a standalone JNI with NDK.

Comment: so remove all java stuff: it should be: `find jnilibrary/src/
jnilibrary/src/
jnilibrary/src/main
jnilibrary/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
jnilibrary/src/main/jni
jnilibrary/src/main/jni/test.c
`

Comment: So, you want to create a standalone android native library .so or .a right? , you can use an android.mk file to create a makefile, and then type ndk-build.

Comment: @uelordi in this scenario, no android studio involved? It's all command-line?

Comment: so isn't your `Library Moidule` build into `.aar` archive?

Comment: No, it's .so files per architecture.

Comment: where are they? see `build/outputs/aar`

Comment: It's not in front of me, but it was something like intermediates/cmake

Comment: I'm using the hello-jni sample from Google

Comment: yeah, it was another way to compile the libraries, because android studio is more oriented to create an apk.

Comment: @uelordi AS it is not more oriented to create an apk: just use `apply plugin: 'com.android[.model].library'` instead of `apply plugin: 'com.android[.model].application'` in your `build.gradle` file

Comment: Sorry @pskink, it was my fault, I didn't know, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @uelordi sure, 
de nada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio model is Project-centered, where a project is an application. You can have an empty application, but it may be useful to create a basic app that will help you test your native library.

You can put all your native code in a separate *Library* module. Note that this will involve the Java wrapper, too. JNI library for Android is useless without a Java wrapper, even if it only declares the **native** methods and defines the static constructor to invoke **System.loadLibrary()**.

You can distribute the JNI library with the Java wrapper class (or classes) in compiled form, or in text form, as you choose.